# Should App connect with SEED NODE or CLUSTER NODE of cassandra?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, seed

Application based on NodeJS is working with Cassandra (1 seed node and 2 nodes).

Should Cassandra connect with Seed node or Regular cluster nodes?

Is it same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The driver discovers the ring information and connects to all nodes selected by the load balancing policy.

You can use any nodes as contact points.